# Unable to Receive POST data on confimation_url after providing the proof on registration URL in Shopware 6.4

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I am trying to create an extension for my app system to connet to shopware 6.4.

I have been following the path as suggested on shopware's app based guide system on
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide#confirmation-request
but after the few steps once the regiseation step was done and confirmation_url along with proof and shop secret were returned it says that ill recieve the necessary data on the confirmation_url that i have provided, bu the request i m getting on the confirmation after succesfully installing the extension doesnt hold any data in POST or GET but i do get shopware Store Signature in Headers.

```
$getVariables = $_GET;
$postVariables = $_POST;
$requestVariables = $_REQUEST;
$headers = getallheaders();
$data = "\n\nGET Variables:\n";
foreach ($getVariables as $key => $value) {
    $data .= "$key: $value" . PHP_EOL;
}
$data .= "\n\nPOST Variables:\n";
foreach ($postVariables as $key => $value) {
    $data .= "$key: $value" . PHP_EOL;
}
$data .= "\n\nREQUEST Variables:\n";
foreach ($requestVariables as $key => $value) {
    $data .= "$key: $value" . PHP_EOL;
}
$data .= "\n\nHeaders:\n";
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    $data .= "$header: $value" . PHP_EOL;
}
$filePath = 'confirm_data.txt';
$file = fopen($filePath, 'a');
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

using above code to save any kind of request on my confirmation_url to text file as i am still in early stages, GET and POST request from other domaims are getting logged properly but for Shopware only reciving headers no POST data.

[Sample of Request that I received from Shopware in Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U2iQ.png)

Can someone explain wat i m doing wrong, and what steps i should take to get the POST data on my confirmation_url page as they are required for me to make a succesfull API request.

after the successfull request i am suppose to recive the folloing data in POST data along with shop signature.

```
{
  "apiKey":"SWIARXBSDJRWEMJONFK2OHBNWA",
  "secretKey":"Q1QyaUg3ZHpnZURPeDV3ZkpncXdSRzJpNjdBeWM1WWhWYWd0NE0",
  "timestamp":"1592398983",
  "shopUrl":"http:\/\/my.shop.com",
  "shopId":"sqX6cqHi6hbj"
}
```

Receiving necessary POST data form shopware store to begin my API connection using extension for my App-System.

Answer (score 0):

The payload of the confirmation comes in the [request body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages) in form of a JSON string. While the method used is `POST`, the `$_POST` super global is intended to be empty, as the `Content-Type` is expected to be `application/json`.

To get the payload from the request body using plain PHP:

```php
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$payload = json_decode($requestBody, true, 512, \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

For reference see the [`app-php-sdk`](https://github.com/shopware/app-php-sdk/blob/main/src/Registration/RegistrationService.php#L96).